# Email Service Provider Script

Tags: web-apps, php, email, web-services

I need a script that allows me to provide email services to end-users.

The script should allow user registration, user management, different levels of service plans, options for payment gateways, spam control, dmarc, dkim... An email with a custom domain... Maybe a Drive for storing large files.

Is there such a thing at all?

Comment: You are looking for an SMTP server, not a script

Comment: Do you have an account on an hosting? Because you are going to need an hosting anyway. Or are you going to use your own NAS?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an SMTP server, not a script.

Try [Roundcube](https://roundcube.net/), is open source but if you have an account with cPanel you might already have it.